How to use Gazebo Fortress camera plugin from URDF?
I am trying to define a regular camera to be used in Gazebo Fortress from a robot description topic created from a URDF file. In my urdf.xacro I have included the camera plugin like so:
  <gazebo reference="zed_0_camera_link">
    <sensor type="camera" name="zed_0_camera_sensor">
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <update_rate>5</update_rate>
      <camera>
        <horizontal_fov>${radians(82)}</horizontal_fov>
        <image>
          <width>600</width>
          <height>400</height>
          <format>b8g8r8</format>
        </image>
        <clip>
          <near>0.4</near>
          <far>100.0</far>
        </clip>
      </camera>
      <plugin name="camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
        <alwayson>true</alwayson>
        <updaterate>0.0</updaterate>
        <cameraname>rrbot/camera1</cameraname>
        <imagetopicname>image_raw</imagetopicname>
        <camerainfotopicname>camera_info</camerainfotopicname>
        <framename>camera_link</framename>
        <hackbaseline>0.07</hackbaseline>
        <distortionk1>0.0</distortionk1>
        <distortionk2>0.0</distortionk2>
        <distortionk3>0.0</distortionk3>
        <distortiont1>0.0</distortiont1>
        <distortiont2>0.0</distortiont2>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>

But get the error:
Could not find shared library libgazebo_ros_camera.so
If I set GZ_SIM_SYSTEM_PLUGIN_PATH to /opt/ros/humble/lib, then I get:
    Library [/opt/ros/humble/lib/libgazebo_ros_camera.so] does not export any plugins. The symbol [IgnitionPluginHook] is missing, or it is not externally visible.

I have also tried pointing GZ_SIM_SYSTEM_PLUGIN_PATH to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gazebo-11/plugins/ and change the plugin filename to libCameraPlugin.so but still same error.
I guess I am unsure of how to do this with Gazebo Fortress, as there is barely any documentation to address this. I have looked on various forums but can't really see anyone else having the same issue as me. I am pretty sure this would work with Gazebo classic (but haven't tried).
